# Insert into a table several values in a temp table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000

I have several values in a temp table called #tempIQ and I want to insert into a table called IQGroups using the same Group identifier.   Assuming everyone has a unique IQ:

```
create table #tempIQ
(
id int
)

declare @GroupIDas int
set @GroupID=1001    

select iq from #tempIQ

1,2,86,99,101,165,180,201
```

I want to insert these ids from the temp table into a grouping called IQGroups but am having difficulty finding a simple solution.

```
-- now try and insert all the iqs for a group into the IQGroups table from the #tempIQ table.
  insert into IQGroups (GroupID, IQ) values (@GroupID, #tempiQ.iq)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
 INSERT INTO IQGroups (GroupID, IQ)
   SELECT @GroupID, IQ
   FROM #tempIQ
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using the SELECT statement.

```
INSERT INTO IQGroups (GroupID, IQ)
SELECT @GroupID, iq
FROM #tempIQ
```

This is the standard way to select multiple rows.

Answer (score 0):

this is another way to do this,

```
select id, 1001 as GroupID
into IQGroups 
from #tempIQ
```